# iPhone rotation causes memory warning

Tags: iphone, autorotate

I am introducing auto-rotation to my app and I'm having an issue with a memory warning. Whatever orientation I start my app in, as long as the device remains in that orientation, I get no memory warnings. However, the first time I rotate the device the following warning is placed on the console: Safari got memory level warning, killing all documents except active. When this happens all view controllers, other than the one be viewed, are unloaded - this produces unexpected behaviors when navigating back to view controllers that should normally already be on the stack. The app never crashes and this warning occurs once upon the first rotation, after that it never happens (until I stop/start the app again). Also, this only happens on the device - no memory warning when running in simulator.

Has anyone seen this behavior? In any case, does anyone have any suggestions on what I might try in order to remove the memory warning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that memory warnings will never happen; you have to handle them gracefully. Suggestions:

- Check for memory leaks with Leaks (note that it doesn't catch all leaks).
- Fix your view controllers to handle a view reload. Specifically (unless you override -(void)loadView), it'll call -(void)viewDidUnload on a memory warning and -(void)viewDidLoad when it becomes visible again. You might fix this by saving state in the view controller and restoring it to the views in -(void)viewDidLoad.
- If you can't be bothered handling the memory warning, implement -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning and do not super-call (i.e. comment out `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]`). This is lazy, and might cause a crash if your app ends up using too much memory (background apps like Safari and Phone will be killed first).

You can test memory warning behaviour with the "simulate memory warning" option in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Memory warnings are part of a normal iOS behavior, due to its limited memory, especially now that multi-tasking is supported.

UIKit doesn’t only allow navigation back from a view controller, but also allows navigation to other view controllers from existing ones. In such a case, a new UIViewController will be allocated, and then loaded into view. The old view controller will go off-screen and becomes inactive, but still owns many objects – some in custom properties and variables and others in the view property/hierarchy. And so does the new visible view controller, in regard to its view objects.

Due to the limited amount of memory of mobile devices, owning the two sets of objects – one in the off-screen view controller and another in the on-screen view controller – might be too much to handle. If UIKit deems it necessary, it can reclaim some of the off-screen view controller’s memory, which is not shown anyway; UIKit knows which view controller is on-screen and which is off-screen, as after all, it is the one managing them (when you call presentModalViewController:animated: or dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:). So, every time it feels pressured, UIKit generates a memory warning, which unloads and releases your off-screen view from the view hierarchy, then call your custom viewDidUnload method for you to do the same for your properties and variables. UIKit releases self.view automatically, allowing us then to manually release our variables and properties in our viewDidUnload code. It does so for all off-screen view controllers.

When the system is running out of memory, it fires a didReceiveMemoryWarning. Off-screen views will be reclaimed and released upon memory warning, but your on-screen view will not get released – it is visible and needed. In case your class owns a lot of memory, such as caches, images, or the like, didReceiveMemoryWarning is where you should purge them, even if they are on-screen; otherwise, your app might be terminated for glutting system resources. You need to override this method to make sure you clean up your memory; just remember you call [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];.

An even more elaborate explanation is available here: http://myok12.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/custom-uiviewcontrollers-their-views-and-their-memory-management/